# What is the default password of hive

Tags: hadoop

With local console, typing "hive" launching the console directly without any password.

But, when I try to connect using dbeaver/beeline, it prompts for username/password.

I tried with

- hive/""
- ""/""
- mysql metastore username/password.
- entries mentioned in hive-site.xml

But none of them are working, Even I tried all the steps in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362166/how-to-get-database-username-and-password-in-hive)

What might be the default username/password, please suggest. Or do I need to configure anything to access like this through jdbc?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add `auth=none` to your JDBC conn. string?

Comment: Yes it is there but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Trying blank username/password worked for me. I am trying with hive user and keytab.